# I've checked everything, but it still says the AutoFilter method of Range class failed, where is the error?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sheet1.Range("B4:B" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & TextBox1.Value & ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you remove the quotes?

Sheet1.Range("B4:B" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=  TextBox1.Value

Where is the textbox1 located? is this a userform or an object in a sheet?